How can I write the following expression in LaTeX using the 'overset' and 'underset' tags?
How can I write the following expression in LaTeX? I want a solution specifically using overset and underset tags.


The way I have approached these things in the past is by using overset and underset, with \joinrel connecting a lot of = signs.

Hi, I have also tried the overset and underset but couldn't executed it correctly. Could you post a solution plz?

Should the "A" character on the left and the two "A" characters above the double line have the same size? Or should the latter two be smaller than the one on the left? Please advise.

Can you choose a title for your question which will help future users with the problem to find your question?

This is the way I usually do this. Pardon me if there are more standard ways.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[A_6:\overset{A_1(a),A_2(b)}{\underset{c}{=\joinrel=\joinrel=\joinrel=\joinrel=\joinrel=\joinrel=}}r_1\]
\end{document}



You can use \xlongequal from the extarrows package; it has the same syntax as \xrightarrow from amsmath.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{A}_6 {:} \xlongequal[c]{\mathcal{A}_1(a),\mathcal{A}_2(b)} r_1
\]

\end{document}



Here's an array-based solution.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx} % optional: Times Roman-clone text and math fonts
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalpha} % restore default math-caligraphic letterin
\begin{document}

\[
  \mathcal{A}_6{:} \,
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 
    \mathcal{A}_1(a),\mathcal{A}_2(b) \\
    \hline\hline
    c
  \end{array}
  \, r_1
\]

\end{document}

